# Separate an array with specific value

Tags: php, arrays

I am committed a project of travel website.In hotel page client required that hotles will list with corresponding place.Exp(A and B are tow places,its id is1 and 2 respectively.when listing hotel first list hotels under the A after that B).   I have an PHP array I am trying to separate this array with place,here 3 different places is there 1,9,10
One array only with place==1 and 2nd array only with place==9 and 3rd array place==10.

Here is my array:

```
Array(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => ARCADIA REGENCY
            [place] => 1

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => HAVELI BACKWATER RESORT
            [place] => 1

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => RAMADA ALLEPPEY
            [place] => 1

        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
            [name] => ORCHID HIGHLANDS
            [place] => 9

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [name] => PLUM JUDY
            [place] => 9

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [name] => THE PANORAMIC GETAWAY
            [place] => 9

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24
            [name] => TEA CASTLE
            [place] => 9

        )




    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 52
            [name] => PERIYAR MEADOWS
            [place] => 10

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 53
            [name] => THE ELEPHANT COURT
            [place] => 10

        )
)
```

I want separate this array with place

Comment: try foreach loop

Comment: Try to say what went wrong and what you have tried so far, so we can better help you. Please include errors and output in possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array();

foreach($old_arr as $key => $item)
{
    if(array_key_exists('place', $item))
        $arr[$item['place']][$key] = $item;
}

ksort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

However, it will drop inner arrays without a Place.